# Gson get call not working

Tags: java, gson, json

I have the following JSONObject:

```
{
  "message": {
    "test1": {
      "abc": -1.23,
      "def": 3.4
    },
    "testID": "sfs332-sdf2-adfdsfds-sfsdfdsgs",
    "msgType": "TEST_MSG",
    "test2": {
      "abc": -7.23,
      "def": 4.23
    }
  }
}
```

I am using the following call:

```
//testObject is JSONObject
testObject.get("testID").getAsString();
```

The call above is returning `null`.  Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your `{` and `}`'s correctly, only `testObject.get("message").getAsString();` will return anything, because everything else is contained within `"message"`.

Comment: will accept shortly- perhaps others can avoid answering as there is no need

Comment: Glad it was a simple fix, at least. Bracketing always messes me up, that's why I gravitate towards formats that use tags (like XML) or compulsory indentation (like python code).